# When I write to a file in C it writes in different lines. How can I write it in one line?

Tags: c

This is part of my code of a task management system and I want to write an entry to a file in the format:
Math HW,Math,Do page 9-15,2022/04/02,TD

I will also need to append many lines like this so is it sensible to use 'w'? I'm still a beginner to C.

But with the code below the entry that's being written to the file looks like this:

```
Math
,ath HW
,o page 9-15
,2022/04/02,TD
```

I'm not sure why this is happening

This is my add_task function:

```
void add_task()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char name[20];
    char category[20];
    char info[50];
    char date[20];
    char status[20];
    char another = 'Y';

    fptr = fopen("Tasks.txt","r");

    if (fptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nSYSTEM ERROR");

        fptr = fopen("Tasks.txt","w");

        getchar();

        return;
    }
    while ( another == 'Y'|| another == 'y')
    {
        fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_END); 
        printf("\nTo Add a new task enter the details below\n");
        printf("Name of Task:");
        getchar();
        fgets(name,50,stdin);
        printf("Category of Task:");
        getchar();
        fgets(category,50,stdin);
        printf("Information about task(Max 49 characters):");
        getchar();
        fgets(info, 50, stdin);
        printf("Due Date of Task(yyyy/mm/dd):");
        scanf(" %s", date);
        printf("Status of Task\n TD = To-Do\n IP = In Progress\n CT = Completed Task\nEnter Status:");
        scanf(" %s", status);
        fprintf(fptr,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", name, category, info, date, status);

        printf("\nDo you want to add another record (Y/N)");

        fflush(stdin);
        another = getchar();
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    printf("\n\n\tPress any key to exit");

    exit(0);
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is non-standard and should be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets()` in `fgets(name,50,stdin);` reads AND includes the `'\n'` as part of the buffer it fills (`name` in this example).

To remove the `'\n'` simply overwrite it with a `'\0'`. To remove the newline from the end of any string, you can use:

```c
  name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;
```

`strcspn (name, "\n")` returns the number of characters in name that do NOT include `"\n"` -- i.e. the index of the `'\n'` at the end of `name`.  Use the same `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;` after each buffer you fill with `fgets()`.

You will need to `#include <string.h>` to make the string functions available.

**Short Example**

There are several other areas to fix.

- First, never hardcode filenames in a function. You shouldn't have to re-compile your code just to read or write to a different filename. Pass the name in as an argument to your program (that's what `int argc, char **argv` are for in `int main (int argc, char **argv) { .. }`. It's fine to provide `"Tasks.txt"` as a default name to use if no argument is provided.
- Never use `scanf()` and `%s` without using a *field-width* modifier. It is no safer than `gets()` that way. If `status` was `20` characters in size, you would need to use `"%19s"` to prevent potential buffer overrun.
- But don't use `scanf()` anyway to read plain text. `fgets()` avoid many, many pitfalls for the new C programmer. Further, even if you do need numeric conversions, read with `fgets()` anyway and then use `sscanf()` to separate the values.
- pass the open `fptr` as an argument to `add_task()`. That way you open the file (and validate the file is open) in `main()`. If you can't open the file in main, there is no need to make the function call in the first place.
- when using `fclose()` after writing to the file, always check the return of `fclose()` to catch any error that may have occurred since your last call to `fprintf()`.

Putting all those pieces together, you could do something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 50     /* if you neeed a constant, #define one (or more) */

void add_task (FILE *fptr)
{
  char name[MAXC];            /* use constant to set buffer size */
  char category[MAXC];
  char info[MAXC];
  char date[MAXC];
  char status[MAXC];
  char another[MAXC] = "Y";   /* let's you use fgets() here as well */
  
  fseek (fptr,0,SEEK_END);              /* only needed once for writes */
  
  while ( another[0] == 'Y'|| another[0] == 'y')  /* check 1st char */
  {
    /* unless you have a numeric conversion, fputs() will do */
    fputs ("\nTo Add a new task enter the details below\n\n"
            "Name of Task: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (name, MAXC, stdin)) {   /* ALWAYS validate each input */
      return;
    }
    name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;     /* trim \n from end of name */
    
    fputs ("Category of Task: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (category, MAXC, stdin)) {     /* ditto */
      return;
    }
    category[strcspn (category, "\n")] = 0;   /* ditto */
    
    printf ("Information about task (Max %d characters): ", MAXC-1);
    if (!fgets (info, MAXC, stdin)) {         /* ditto */
      return;
    }
    info[strcspn (info, "\n")] = 0;           /* ditto */
    
    fputs ("Due Date of Task(yyyy/mm/dd): ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (date, MAXC, stdin)) {         /* ditto */
      return;
    }
    date[strcspn (date, "\n")] = 0;           /* ditto */
    
    fputs ("Status of Task\n TD = To-Do\n IP = In Progress\n"
            " CT = Completed Task\nEnter Status: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (status, MAXC, stdin)) {       /* ditto */
      return;
    }
    status[strcspn (status, "\n")] = 0;       /* ditto */
    
    fprintf (fptr, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", name, category, info, date, status);

    fputs ("\nDo you want to add another record (Y/N): ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (another, MAXC, stdin)) {      /* ditto */
      return;
    }
  }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  /* use filename provided as 1st argument ("Tasks.txt" default) */
  FILE *fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "Tasks.txt", "w");

  if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for writing */
    perror ("file open failed");
    return 1;
  }
  
  add_task (fp);                /* add your tasks */

  if (fclose (fp) == EOF) {     /* always check close-after-write */
    perror ("fclose(fptr)");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

**Example Use**

Adding two tasks:

```
$ ./bin/addtask

To Add a new task enter the details below

Name of Task: Math
Category of Task: HW
Information about task (Max 49 characters): pages 9-15
Due Date of Task(yyyy/mm/dd): 2022/04/02
Status of Task
 TD = To-Do
 IP = In Progress
 CT = Completed Task
Enter Status: TD

Do you want to add another record (Y/N): Y

To Add a new task enter the details below

Name of Task: Science
Category of Task: HW
Information about task (Max 49 characters): pages 100-125
Due Date of Task(yyyy/mm/dd): 2022/05/01
Status of Task
 TD = To-Do
 IP = In Progress
 CT = Completed Task
Enter Status: TD

Do you want to add another record (Y/N): n
```

**Resulting File**

```
$ cat Tasks.txt
Math,HW,pages 9-15,2022/04/02,TD
Science,HW,pages 100-125,2022/05/01,TD
```

**Using Array of `struct` and `qsort()` by date**

When you need to handle a collection of separate data as a single object, C provides a `struct` that allows you to do it. You simply add all the variables that need to be treated as a single object to the struct. To handle multiple objects, you then create an array of struct.

To sort the array by any one variable in the struct, you simply write a `qsort()` `compare()` function. Simple enough, the prototype is:

```c
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
```

There `a` and `b` will be pointers to elements in your array. In your compare function, you simply cast them back to the type they are. In this case if you have an array of `struct task`, then each element is a `task`. Since `a` and `b` are pointers to `task`, you just cast them back as `task *x = a;` and `task *y = b;`.

Now just write how you want the elements compared. Since you have a pointer to `task` and you want to sort by the `date` member, you can simply `return strcmp (x->date, y->date);` The `qsort()` `compare()` function could then be:

```c
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const task *x = a;    /* a and b are pointers or elements in your array */
  const task *y = b;    /* so you cast back to type task* (pointer) */
  
  return strcmp (x->date, y->date);   /* simply use strcmp() for comparison */
}
```

You call `qsort()` as:

```c
  qsort (arr, n, sizeof *arr, compare);   /* sort arr by date - ascending */
```

Done, sorted.

Putting all the pieces together and extending your example, you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 50     /* if you neeed a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct task {
  char name[MAXC];            /* use constant to set buffer size */
  char category[MAXC];
  char info[MAXC];
  char date[MAXC];
  char status[MAXC];
} task;

int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const task *x = a;    /* a and b are pointers or elements in your array */
  const task *y = b;    /* so you cast back to type task* (pointer) */
  
  return strcmp (x->date, y->date);   /* simply use strcmp() for comparison */
}

void add_task (FILE *fptr)
{
  task arr[MAXC] = {{ .name = "" }};  /* declare an array of 50 struct */
  int n = 0;                          /* counter for array index */
  char another[MAXC] = "Y";           /* let's you use fgets() here as well */
  
  fseek (fptr,0,SEEK_END);              /* only needed once for writes */
  
  while (n < MAXC && (another[0] == 'Y'|| another[0] == 'y'))
  {
    /* unless you have a numeric conversion, fputs() will do */
    fputs ("\nTo Add a new task enter the details below\n\n"
            "Name of Task: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (arr[n].name, MAXC, stdin)) { /* ALWAYS validate each input */
      return;
    }
    arr[n].name[strcspn (arr[n].name, "\n")] = 0;   /* trim \n from end */
    
    fputs ("Category of Task: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (arr[n].category, MAXC, stdin)) {            /* ditto */
      return;
    }
    arr[n].category[strcspn (arr[n].category, "\n")] = 0;   /* ditto */
    
    printf ("Information about task (Max %d characters): ", MAXC-1);
    if (!fgets (arr[n].info, MAXC, stdin)) {                /* ditto */
      return;
    }
    arr[n].info[strcspn (arr[n].info, "\n")] = 0;           /* ditto */
    
    fputs ("Due Date of Task(yyyy/mm/dd): ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (arr[n].date, MAXC, stdin)) {                /* ditto */
      return;
    }
    arr[n].date[strcspn (arr[n].date, "\n")] = 0;           /* ditto */
    
    fputs ("Status of Task\n TD = To-Do\n IP = In Progress\n"
            " CT = Completed Task\nEnter Status: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (arr[n].status, MAXC, stdin)) {              /* ditto */
      return;
    }
    arr[n].status[strcspn (arr[n].status, "\n")] = 0;       /* ditto */
    
    n += 1;       /* increment index after all good inputs */
    
    fputs ("\nDo you want to add another record (Y/N): ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (another, MAXC, stdin)) {      /* ditto */
      return;
    }
  }
  
  qsort (arr, n, sizeof *arr, compare);   /* sort arr by date - ascending */
  
  puts ("\nWriting the following to file:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    /* output to screen */
    printf ("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", arr[i].name,  arr[i].category,  arr[i].info, 
                                arr[i].date,  arr[i].status);
    /* output to file */
    fprintf (fptr, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",  arr[i].name,  arr[i].category,  
                                        arr[i].info,  arr[i].date, 
                                        arr[i].status);
  }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  /* use filename provided as 1st argument ("Tasks.txt" default) */
  FILE *fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "Tasks.txt", "w");

  if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for writing */
    perror ("file open failed");
    return 1;
  }
  
  add_task (fp);                /* add your tasks */

  if (fclose (fp) == EOF) {     /* always check close-after-write */
    perror ("fclose(fptr)");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/addtask2

To Add a new task enter the details below

Name of Task: Math
Category of Task: HW
Information about task (Max 49 characters): too many pages
Due Date of Task(yyyy/mm/dd): 2022/05/10
Status of Task
 TD = To-Do
 IP = In Progress
 CT = Completed Task
Enter Status: TD

Do you want to add another record (Y/N): Y

To Add a new task enter the details below

Name of Task: Science
Category of Task: HW
Information about task (Max 49 characters): Lots of science
Due Date of Task(yyyy/mm/dd): 2022/05/01
Status of Task
 TD = To-Do
 IP = In Progress
 CT = Completed Task
Enter Status: TD

Do you want to add another record (Y/N): n

Writing the following to file:

Science,HW,Lots of science,2022/05/01,TD
Math,HW,too many pages,2022/05/10,TD
```

As you can see above, the `arr` is now sorted by the `date` member of each struct.

Comment: So where do I write this line?  ` name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: You write it after each call to `fgets()`, e.g. `fgets(name,50,stdin);` then `name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;` and then after `fgets(category,50,stdin);` do `category[strcspn (category, "\n")] = 0;` and so on.

Comment: Oh okayy got it! I will try it now

Comment: Math,ath HW,o page 9-15,2022/04/03,TD It write to the file like this now

Comment: It shouldn't, (unless you entered `"Math,ath"`) but can you see what is wrong with `fgets(name,50,stdin);` and your definition of `char name[20];`?  Check the amount you are reading into each of your buffers. You should include a `'\n'` at the end of `"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n"` in `fprintf(fptr,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", name, category, info, date, status);`

Comment: Also, unless you are using `cl.exe` (the Microsoft compiler), `fflush(stdin);` invokes *Undefined Behavior* according to the C-standard. Unless you are using VS, remove that line -- it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Your missing char issue looks related to all the unnecessary `getchar();` calls. Mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` is killing you.

Comment: so do I remove the getchar()?

Comment: Yes, and change ALL your inputs to `fgets()`. `scanf()` is so full of pitfalls for the new C programmer -- you are just asking for grief (and you are getting it). `fgets()` will consume a whole line of input on each read, no need for `getchar()` after `fgets()`.

Comment: Alright I will do that. But regarding the date is there a way I can still compare other dates when its in a string format?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245714/discussion-between-hannahj-and-david-c-rankin).

Comment: Hey there @DavidC.Rankin. Should it be  `if(fgets(name, 50, stdin) != NULL){ then do somehting} ` So I am not totally understand ` if (!fgets (name, MAXC, stdin)) {return;}`.

Comment: @Mark Generally you will want to remove the trailing `'\n'` included by `fgets()`. So include `string.h` and then turn your test around and only handle the error on failure, e.g. `if(fgets(name, 50, stdin) == NULL) { puts ("user canceled input"); return 1 } name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;` Where `strcspn()` just returns the number of characters before the `'\n'` allowing you to overwrite the `'\n'` with `0` (the nul-terminating character). Now use `name` however you need.  Note: you can use the shorthand test `if (!(fgets(name, 50, stdin)) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

The function [`fgets()`](https://m.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) reads input until newline, the newline is included in the string if the maximum length is not exceeded.  You need to strip the newline from the end of strings entered via `fgets()`.

Solutions to that at [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)